# Getting and error when using Scanner in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to pull an input from the user for this program to start on some more complicated stuff. However no matter what I try I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

I am running this code here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner test = new Scanner(System.in);
    String x = test.nextLine();
    System.out.println(x);

  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks ok. Are you running this in an online compiler?

Comment: Yes, can that cause issues?

Comment: It depends on the site. If I run your code on [ideone](https://ideone.com/hW9mo3) I get that error if I don't put anything in the "INPUT" box. Check your compiler for something like that. You probably need to enter all the text for stdin ahead of time.

Comment: Okay, I may try a different compiler. Is there a way to write this in a way that would wait until after you type an input instead of pulling right away?

Comment: It already does wait. If you ran this code in a console on your pc, it would work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check before if `nextLine()` exists. Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner test = new Scanner(System.in);

      while (test.hasNextLine()) {
         string = test.nextLine();
         System.out.println(string);
      }
   }
}
```